# parar um foreach javaScript

Tags: jquery

Tenho um script que lê cada campo do formulário:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#cadastrar").on("click", function () {

        $(".required").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                idCampo = $(this).attr("id");
                nomeCampo = idCampo.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + idCampo.substr(1);
                alert("Preecha campo " + nomeCampo + ", campo obrigatório");
                $(this).focus();
                return false;
            };
        });
    });
```

E tenho um campo de data no form:

```
<input type="date" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" class="inputTextMedio required" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" required/>
```

Estou tendo 2 problemas aqui.

No `loop foreach`, quando chega no return false ele até para.

Mas mesmo assim parece que continua pois tenho abaixo um `ajax` que só pode ser chamado se as validações ocorrerem normalmente. Mas está passando direto.

```
        foreach.....

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/cadastrarMembro.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {   
                 dataCadastro : $("#dataCadastro").val(),
                 nome : $("#nome").val(),
                 apelido : $("#apelido").val(),
                 nascimento : $("#nascimento").val(),
                 telefone : $("#telefone").val(),
                 celular : $("#celular").val(),
                 bairro : $("#bairro").val(),
                 endereco : $("#endereco").val(),
                 email : $("#email").val(),
                 sexo : $("#sexo").val(),
                 estadoCivil : $("#estadoCivil").val(),
                 dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
                 bloqueado : $("#bloqueado").val(),
                 batizadoFora : $("#batizadoFora").val(),
                 usuario : $("#usuario").val(),
                 senha : $("#senha").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result[0] == "Erro")
                    $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
                else
                    $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
            }
        });


    });


});
```

Onde estou errando?

código completo:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#cadastrar").on("click", function () {

        $(".required").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                idCampo = $(this).attr("id");
                nomeCampo = idCampo.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + idCampo.substr(1);
                alert("Preecha campo " + nomeCampo + ", campo obrigatório");
                $(this).focus();
                break();
            };
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/cadastrarMembro.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {   
                 dataCadastro : $("#dataCadastro").val(),
                 nome : $("#nome").val(),
                 apelido : $("#apelido").val(),
                 nascimento : $("#nascimento").val(),
                 telefone : $("#telefone").val(),
                 celular : $("#celular").val(),
                 bairro : $("#bairro").val(),
                 endereco : $("#endereco").val(),
                 email : $("#email").val(),
                 sexo : $("#sexo").val(),
                 estadoCivil : $("#estadoCivil").val(),
                 dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
                 bloqueado : $("#bloqueado").val(),
                 batizadoFora : $("#batizadoFora").val(),
                 usuario : $("#usuario").val(),
                 senha : $("#senha").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result[0] == "Erro")
                    $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
                else
                    $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
            }
        });


    });


});
```

Também tentei da forma abaixo e nada.

```
requeridos = $(".required");
eachConta = requeridos.length;
alert(eachConta);

for (i=0; i< eachConta; i++) {
    if (requeridos[i].val() == "") {
        idCampo = requeridos[i].attr("id");
        nomeCampo = idCampo.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + idCampo.substr(1);
        alert("Preecha campo " + nomeCampo + ", campo obrigatório");
        requeridos[i].focus();
        return false;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `return false` irá fazer efeito na função do `.each` (porque está dentro dela), não na função do click. Ou seja, o loop será abortado quando o `if` for satisfeito, mas o resto do código será processado normalmente.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma variável inicialmente `true` e quando o `if` for atendido, alterar para `false` e colocar o Ajax dentro de outro `if` verificando se a variável continua `true`:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#cadastrar").on("click", function () {

         var valida = true;

         $(".required").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                idCampo = $(this).attr("id");
                nomeCampo = idCampo.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + idCampo.substr(1);
                alert("Preecha campo " + nomeCampo + ", campo obrigatório");
                $(this).focus();
                valida = false;
                return false;
            };
        });        

        if(valida){

            // código do Ajax
        }

    });
});
```

Com `for` daria certo com o `return false`, porque não teria uma segunda função. Só que no seu `for` da pergunta, possui dois erros: `requeridos[i].val()` e 
`requeridos[i].attr("id")`. Os métodos `.val()` e `.attr()` requerem objetos jQuery. O correto seria:

```
var requeridos = $(".required");
eachConta = requeridos.length;

for (i=0; i< eachConta; i++) {
    if ($(requeridos[i]).val() == "") {
        idCampo = $(requeridos[i]).attr("id");
        nomeCampo = idCampo.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + idCampo.substr(1);
        alert("Preecha campo " + nomeCampo + ", campo obrigatório");
        requeridos[i].focus();
        return false;
    };

}

// código do Ajax
```

Comment: que vergonha. kkk. Obrigado! cansaço faz coisas

Comment: mas, e o problema do campo de data?

Comment: Qual seria o problema com o campo?

Comment: então, o campo é esse <input type="date" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" class="inputTextMedio" name="dataBatismo" id="dataBatismo"/>. Se eu escolher uma data tudo certo. Mas se eu não escolher da erro na query mysql e no mysql o campo aceita vazio ou nulo

Comment: no ajax do jquery, antes de enviar para o php, fiz assim  $_POST["dataBatismo"] == "" ? 'NULL' : $_POST["dataBatismo"] ,, uma vez que o campo aceita valor nulo

Comment: Tenta usar `empty($_POST["dataBatismo"]) ? 'NULL' : $_POST["dataBatismo"]`

Comment: mesma coisa. Antigamente abríamos o imspector dos browsers e conseguíamos ver o retorno do php para o ajax. Agora às vezes nem o javascript direito estão exibindo no ispector